# Starting Libeoffice from the command line opening a csv file does not produce a clickable launcher icon

Tags: launcher, libreoffice

Whenever I open a cvs file from the command line using the cmd 'libreoffice --calc my_file' and libreoffice was not previously started I do not get a launcher icon for libreoffice calc. Therefore whenever I open or activate any other program I need to minimize that window in order to get to the calc window again.

The error might seam un-important, but I work a lot with csv files and the command line. And to always have to minimize the window in front of the Libreoffice calc instance is TEDIOUS!

I have read some questions describing exactly the same issue here and none of them was answered with a way to FIX that issue. Just some (working) time by time workarounds.

The one that did work for me is to 'xkill' the launcher. Afterwards I have the calc icon. But that is not really a good solution!

Please this can not be too hard to fix!
Oh - I use Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

Its a bug in libreoffice see [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1026426) for more information and you can report your state